# Fast forward inside a quotation to remove obsolete information?

Tags: american-english, quotes, quotations, ellipses, quotation-marks

Would it be correct to fast forward inside a quotation to remove obsolete information by using three periods (...) as shown in the following examples?

1. “ ‘Do you want me to question this boy?’ Justice Asked. … ‘No!’ Harris
   said violently, explosively. ‘Damnation! Send him out of here!’ ”
2. “ ‘Do you want me to question this boy?’ Justice Asked.” … “ ‘No!’ Harris said violently, explosively. ‘Damnation! Send him out of here!’ ”

or would I just have the full quote?

### Full Quote

> " 'Do you want me to question this boy?' But he
>   could hear, and during those subsequent long seconds while there was absolutely no sound in the crowded little room save that of quiet and intent breathing it was as if he had swung outward at the end of a grape vine, over a ravine, and at the top of the swing had been caught in a prolonged instant of mesmerized gravity, weightless in time.
>
> 'No!' Harris said violently, explosively. 'Damnation! Send him out of here!' "

Comment: why are you doing this?

Comment: For a research paper, and to use for future reference when I am writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [The Punctuation Guide](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/ellipses.html):

> An ellipsis is a set of three periods ( . . . ) indicating an omission. Each period should have a single space on either side, except when adjacent to a quotation mark, in which case there should be no space.

your sentences are correct.

Comment: Ah, forgot to read that website, But thank you! This helps.

Answer (score 0):

Rather that just a ellipsis as in the other answer, another option is an ellipsis within square brackets - see this ELU [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/5975).

Quoting [grammar-monster.com](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/brackets_round_and_square_brackets.htm)

> Ellipsis is used to show text omitted from a quote. Ellipsis is usually written "..." or "[...]"
>
> For example:
>   *It's no small irony that the government [...] ends up promoting precisely that which they would most like to repress.*
>   (The ellipsis replaces "inevitably and invariably".). 
>   *Andy Warhol is the only genius...with an IQ of 60.*
>   (The ellipsis replaces the words "I've ever known" in this Gore Vidal quote.).