# Can you use square brackets to correct punctuation in quotes?

Tags: punctuation, quotations, square-brackets

I know why we use square brackets in quotations. But can we also use it for changing punctuation, in order to make it fit better with the sentence?

For instance:

Original Quote: "We went to the mall today, and had a lot of fun."

Bracketed Quote: "[They] went to the mall today[.]"

I'm doing this because I want to include only part of the statement, and not all of it. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper use of \[square brackets\] in quotes?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2271/what-is-the-proper-use-of-square-brackets-in-quotes)

Comment: You never need to put a period in brackets. In this case, where a comma is replaced by a period, just put a period *outside* the quotation marks, and then it belongs to your text, not the quoted material.

Comment: No. Try: *They said, "We went to the mall today..."*  or *They said that they "went to the mall" that day.*

Comment: @niamulbengali no it didn't say anything about punctuation.

Comment: @TinfoilHat I like the first one with the ellipsis, since the actual quote I'm trying to use is quite big and not in-text. I'll be using that.

Comment: @Robusto, putting the period outside the quotation marks is indeed the right thing to do, but it is, alas, liable to get one into trouble if one has the misfortune of labouring  under an editor who is paid to enforce the Chicago rules, even when they are irrational.

Comment: @jsw29: Yeah, nitpickers are ... nitpicky. This leads writers to adopt dodges like adding a superfluous word to avoid the difficulty: "[They] went to the mall today," apparently. Editors also strike those out as well. You can't win.

Comment: As an editor who is paid to enforce the Chicago rules even when they are irrational, I can vouch for jsw29's comment—and my tactic for avoiding the resulting ambiguity is precisely the one that Samantha suggests: adding **[.]** before the close quotation mark.