# Using brackets in quotes to switch "me" to "him"

Tags: word-usage, quotes, square-brackets

Let's say someone says:

> Take me to the store right this second.

I want to quote the person directly but incorporate it into my sentence my changing "me" to "him" as follows:

> He said to "take [him] to the store right this second".

Is this the correct use of the brackets to change the quote?

Comment: It's fine. [It's covered in this question and answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2271/what-is-the-proper-use-of-square-brackets-in-quotes).

Comment: You need to remove the quotes; reported speech is not a quote.

Answer (score 0):

'Say to' is not a normal quotative verb, and so its use as one is at best dubious (though the rules do seem to be relaxing in this area).

From the [Britannica Dictionary](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/Using-Said-with-Direct-and-Indirect-Speech):

> Ask the Editor
>
> **Using "Said" with Direct and Indirect Speech**
>
> When converting indirect speech into direct speech, when should we use
> *said* and *said to*?
>
> Answer
>
> When you are repeating the exact words someone spoke, that is direct
> speech. Use said with quotation marks, as in the examples below:
>
> - She said, "Go home!"
> - He said, "Stop working at 5:00."
> - Mark said, "Turn left on the next street." I said, "I'll be home later." ...
>
> When you are reporting what someone said, but may not be using their
> exact words, that is indirect speech. Use *said to* when reporting a
> command. Use *said that* or *said* when reporting information that was
> given. Do not use quotation marks for indirect speech, as in the
> examples below:
>
> - She said to go home. [*said to* because "go home" is a command]
> - He said to stop working at 5:00.
> - Mark said to turn left on Main Street, which is the next street.
> - I said (that) I'd be home later. [said (that) because "I'll be home later" is information]
> - My mother said (that) I was going to be late.
> - The children all said (that) they were hungry.

You can switch to an accepted quotative verb:

- He demanded "Take [him] to the store right this second"

But this doesn't sound as natural as the obvious quote, and could be confusing. I'm not sure I could ever see an advantage in switching pronouns in this way.

The corresponding report structure:

- He demanded/asked that we [should] take him to the store right that second

is unremarkable, fine.